# request body undefined, mongoose validation error on nested properties

Tags: node.js, express, validation, mongoose, post

I am working a nodejs/express/mongoose

My model:

```
const TodoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: { type: String, required: ['Name is required'] },
},
```

});

Controller :

```
async function createTask(req, res) {
try {
    const task = new Todo({ name: req.body });
    console.log(req);
    console.log('Name check: ', req.name);
    const result = await task.save();
    console.log('check: ', task, result);
    // res.send('Task created: ', result);
    res.json({ msg: 'Task created', item: result });
} catch (error) {
    console.log('Task creation error:', error);
    return res.json({
        msg: error,
    });
}
```

}

My response in postman:

```
    "msg": {
    "errors": {
        "name": {
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "message": "Name is required",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Name is required",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "name"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "name"
        }
    },
    "_message": "Todo validation failed",
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "message": "Todo validation failed: name: Name is required"
}
```

}

and for my logs, req.name is undefined, and req.body.

I saw the docs for mongoose validation, and the type keyword, and tried the recommendations, but nothing helped. What's up with my post endpoint?

Comment: Can You add all code all files,  please?

Comment: hard to tell but have you got the content-type set in the request headers?

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error when You use `required` in Your mongoose Schema, You miss `true` argument.
Here is my example =>

---

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "You Must Provide name"],
    trim: true,
    maxlength: [23, "Maximum twenty characters"],
    minlength: [5, "Minimum four characters"],
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Task", TaskSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you just don`t add middlewares to express.

```html
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```